# Is an undirected graph consisting only two connected vertices cyclic?

Tags: graphs

I have two questions:

1. Does acyclic/cyclic classification only apply to directed graphs?
2. If not, does the following undirected graph have any cycle?

   A --- B

Comment: Have you checked [the definitions of cycle and acyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory))?

Comment: Yes, the important point is that path cannot have repeated edges and vertices except for the first and the last vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1.) No, undirected cycles are also natural.

(2.) No, what you describe is a path on two vertices. It does not form a cycle, since [by definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html), you cannot find a subset of the edges that form a *path* where the first node of the path corresponds to the last.

To be sure about these type of things, you must always look at the definitions.

Comment: The crucial point I think I miss is that a path is a subset of edge set of the graph. It cannot contain same edge more than once. Therefore, in an undirected graph, the path of (AB, BA) is not valid since AB is same as BA.